# Symfony 2 session destroyed

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a nasty problem with Symfony2 session. I have a cart in which I can insert things. I add several items and it works, but on some items the app crashes telling me

`ContextErrorException: Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in ...`

The session is destroyed and I'm logged out of the site.
I have the session stored in the DB and the line about the session is deleted too, like a clean logoff.
I triple checked all the code and I have no code of mine that invalidates the session. I also commented out each line containing `session->invalidate` to no avail.
I noted that the session cleanup comes between the "return" of one function and the following line in my code after the code returns, but there is no code between them. It seems something related to events/listeners but none are configured by me.
I don't know where to check, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71088) and other searches, my guess is you're storing multi-byte strings in your session data and it's getting corrupted. It's also possible the database column storing the data is too short and the string is getting truncated, corrupting it. Here's what I would look at:

- If you're using a database for storage be sure it's prepared for multi-byte strings.
- Make sure your session database column is large enough, e.g. `MEDIUMTEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`.
- Maybe there's a bug in Symfony's session handler (unlikely since that probably would have been caught quickly).
- Maybe you've somehow corrupted your own multi-byte strings. Check you're not using any PHP functions that aren't binary-safe.

If you can't find the root cause I would try overriding the session storage handler and running `base64_encode` over the data before storage and decode after retrieval.  But that's a last resort to work around the real problem.

Comment: I'm using pdo for session storage and the first instruction in the Save method in the symfony class is ```bas64_encode```.
The strange thing is that only some combination of objects in the cart produce the error message.

Comment: To be precise: in the session are stored serialized application objects, when all works correclty I can base64 decode the session content in the DB and see all the serialized objects. In fact if I manually corrupt the data in the DB I get the same error.

Comment: Interesting. You've certainly been thorough looking into it. Have you tried manually deserializing those objects? Maybe the string is safe but unserialize fails. Also, is the serialized object too long for the db column size?

Comment: The field in the DB is of type TEXT, that is enough to contain more object than I have. I can add the same type of object a dozen times with no problem, when I mix objects types even 2 objects create the problem.
I have a problem trying the unserialize test you propose:
1. I add an object of type A, it is ok
2. I add an object of type B. This also is ok. To add the second object I must get the previous order from the session, so I am pretty sure it is de-serialized correctly.
3. If at this point I try to add an object of type A or B I get the error.

Comment: I had some problems using json_array. In my case windows-1252 encoding was causing these errors. Running utf8_encode on specific strings was a workaround for me.

Comment: It sounds like you've covered this, but I was surprised by how big the session data was. It seems Symfony stores the whole user object in there. I got the same `session has been destroyed` error and had to change my `sess_data` column to `MEDIUMBLOB` as recommended [in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html#mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the write e read method of PDOSessionHandler instead of base64encode/decode i put utf8_encode for write and in the read method i put utf8_decode. This workaround works for me but is not a clean solution.   The question now is: why base64encode/decode fails?